# Use awk to match a word, then find the first occurrence of another word

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed, xrandr

I am trying to find a way to re-search for another matching word after I already had a match.

I am specifically trying to get the brightness value of one of my monitors. For example a part of the output of my `xrandr --verbose` is the following:

```
DP-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (0x6e) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
    Identifier: 0x46
    Timestamp:  73906594
    Subpixel:   horizontal rgb
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       1
```

I want to look for the word connected and then get the first occurrence of the word Brightness.

What I have tried which works is the following:

```
xrandr --verbose | awk '/ connected /{print $1}/Brightness:/{print $2}'
```

Which gives me the following output, because I have two monitors:

```
LVDS-1                                                                      
1.0
DP-1
1.0
```

But assuming I only want the first occurrence for a result I have tried this:

```
 xrandr --verbose | awk '/LVDS-1/{getline; getline; getline; getline; getline; print$0}'
```

Which works as intended giving me the value of brightness for this specific monitor.

But I am not sure whether the Brightness value is always on 5 lines later.
So I was looking for a more robust solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***awk*** solution:

```
xrandr --verbose | awk '/LVDS-1/{f=1}/Brightness:/ && f{print $2; exit}'
```

---

- `/LVDS-1/{f=1}` - on encountering line with needed `LVDS-1` set flag `f=1`
- `/Brightness:/ && f` - when encountering the closest line with `Brightness:` and active flag `f` (for `LVDS-1`) - print the value and `exit` the script execution immediately (to avoid redundant iterations)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to print the brightness for a specific monitor. Let's assume that is `LVDS-1`. Then you can use a variable to check that you are in the correct "section" of `xrandr` output and code something like this:

```
xrandr --verbose | awk '/ connected / { if ( $1 == "LVDS-1" ) { print $1; print_brightness = 1; } } /Brightness: / { if (print_brightness) { print $2; print_brightness = 0; } }'
```

Comment: This is also correct and thank you very much for an elaborate answer, I chose Roman's answer though because it was shorter.

Comment: @ChristosTselepidas, not only shorter, it will avoid redundant record iterations

Answer (score 0):

`xrandr --verbose | awk '/connected/,0 { if( /Brightness:/ ) { print $2; exit } }'`

The end-of-range expression `0` is interpreted as `false`, which means that the range will be extended as far as possible once the start-of-range pattern (`/connected/`) matches.